# Celery does not execute all tasks from the group

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to schedule group of tasks from initial task using celery v5.3.6. Once task in the middle of the group failed, other tasks are not executed.

here is sample code:

```python
@shared_task
def success_task(num):
    return num

@shared_task
def failed_task(num):
    raise Exception

@shared_task
def process_task():
    task_group = group(success_task.s(1), failed_task.s(2), failed_task.s(3), success_task.s(4))
    task_group()
```

If call main task synchronously using `process_task()` it works as expected and all tasks are executed, though it does not work if I run the same as async: `process_task.apply_async()`

Comment: Can you verify that the group is done executing? This can be done by calling `task_group..ready()`

Comment: I am also curious about the purpose and functionality of the suffix `| callback` when you define `task_group`.
As I understand it, the pipe operator is either a set union or bitwise OR. What does it do in this context?
EDIT: Never mind. I found [it](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives)

Comment: Yes, it marked as  `ready`, `group | callback` is equivalent to chord, but it actually it doesn't make any difference, so I have simplified example with simple `group` to not confuse.

Comment: What tasks are not executed? And what is the result of executing the group after it is ready?

Comment: `failed_task.s(3), success_task.s(4)` are not executed, and result of the group is `Exception`

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example,? That will make it easier to provide more help.